# How do I query mongodb for user_name given tweet_followers_count

Tags: mongodb

I have some tweet data stored in mondodb and I want to find the user_name of the specific user that has tweet_followers_count of a specific number. How do I do that in mongo? Thank you. 
This is what I have but returns syntax error.

```
db.users.find({"tweet_followers_count=8973882"})
```

Below is what one of the records looks like.

[image]

Comment: Try `db.users.find({"tweet_followers_count":8973882}, {"user_name":1})`

Comment: how do y store records in mongo ? we need to see it

Comment: I added a record of how the data is stored. I don't know the username. For the record that has "tweet_followers_count" that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Building up and executing the following query will return the expected document:

```
var query = { "user_name" : "koteras", "tweet_followers_count" : 461 };

db.users.find(query);
```